# Promise and reference value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I would like to build a promise chain with angular to apply a set of queries:

```
           for(variableIndex in _editableVariable.values) {
                var v = _editableVariable.values[variableIndex];
                if(v.value != v.old_value) {
                    console.log('v', v);
                    var newVariableRes = new VariableValueRes(v);
                    if(v.old_value == undefined) {
                        p.then(function() {
                            console.log('B', newVariableRes);
                            return newVariableRes.$save().$promise;
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log('Try update: ', v);
                        p.then(function() {
                            console.log('C', newVariableRes);
                            return newVariableRes.$update().$promise;
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
```

My issue is when I display the `console.log('v',v)` I got the different `value` for the different variables.
When I am in the promise and I display the `console.log('B', newVariableRes)` the content of `newVariableRes` is the `value` of the latest variable.

**Output exemple:**

```
v 
Object {value: "1", old_value: undefined, platform: "/api/v1/platform/1", product_variable: "/api/v1/product_var/2"}
v 
Object {value: "2", old_value: undefined, platform: "/api/v1/platform/2", product_variable: "/api/v1/product_var/2"}
v 
Object {value: "3", old_value: "", id: 7, platform: "/api/v1/platform/3", product_variable: "/api/v1/product_var/2"}

B 
Resource {value: "3", old_value: "", id: 7, platform: "/api/v1/platform/3", product_variable: "/api/v1/product_var/2"…}
B 
Resource {value: "3", old_value: "", id: 7, platform: "/api/v1/platform/3", product_variable: "/api/v1/product_var/2"…}
C 
Resource {value: "3", old_value: "", id: 7, platform: "/api/v1/platform/3", product_variable: "/api/v1/product_var/2"…}
```

As I am new in javascript, I was thinking that `v` is a reference on the value. Thus `VariableValueRes` takes this reference.
When I change the pointing reference of `v`, this should not change the content of the `VariableValueRes`.

Where is my misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that JS only has global or function scope. So your `v` and `newVariableRes` variables (declared inside your for loop) are treated the same as if they were declared the the top of the surrounding function.

Each iteration of your loop, the value of `v` is updated and logged immediately, showing the value you expected to see. However, by the time your promise callbacks execute, the loop has finished so `v` and `newVariableRes` will hold the last value placed in them.

These callbacks reference `newVariableRes` by closure, meaning that the outer function can finish and the inner function (your callback) still uses the value of this variable from the outer scope, rather than using whatever value was present when the function was created.

This is a very common mistake to see in JS code, and normally the solution is to fix the variable by putting it in a new function scope like so

```
p.then((function(nvr) {
    return function() {
        console.log('B', nvr);
        return nvr.$save().$promise;
    };
})(newVariableRes));
```

This way we create a function, giving it our variable as a parameter. As we don't change this parameter within the *function*, our callback can use it through closure and be sure that it won't change.

A simpler way to do this, as you are using angular already, is to replace your for loop with `angular.forEach` which will solve this problem in exactly the same way for `v`. Now you know `v` will be what you expected originally in your callbacks you can create `new VariableValueRes(v)` inside these callbacks and not have to worry about what `newVariableRes` points to (as you won't be using it).